# How app.use function in ExpressJS redirects urls ending with "/"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

This code will redirect all the URLs that end with a "/" to the same URL but without the "/". For example, if the user navigates to http://localhost:3000/about/, they will be redirected to http://localhost:3000/about. This will make the image URLs and stuff in the HTML files always work correctly.

```
        var express = require('express');
        var app = express();
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {  
            if (req.path.substr(-1) == '/' && req.path.length > 1) {
        var query = req.url.slice(req.path.length);  
res.redirect(301, req.path.slice(0, -1) + query);
 } else {
                next();
            }
});
```

Can anyone explain me whats going on inside this code. In my understanding, if the requested path last index is equal to / and requested path length is greater than 1 then the below codes must be executed.

So if the condition is met, query variable slice the requested url on the basis of the argument it receives as actual path length as requested the redirect function takes slice function as its callback function.

The slice method has two arguments. The first argument takes first index value and -1 takes last index value. It also includes the result in query variable.

Comment: Separate the code block from your question text. Questions in comments are hard to read. Please also format your code with consistent indentation (also for readability).

Comment: But by far the best way to understand this code is to step through it in [the debugger](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use this package

`$ npm install connect-slashes`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-slashes

Then you can use as below

```
var connect = require("connect")
  , slashes = require("connect-slashes");

connect()
  .use(connect.logger())
  .use(connect.static())
  .use(slashes(false))
  .listen(3000);
```

Comment: `slashes(false)`, in that case.